# Embed Tumblr in website using SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl, tumblr, embedding

It is easy enough to embed a Tumblr Blog into another website using a simple script like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://username.tumblr.com/js"></script>
```

However, my question is can this be made secure?  We've recently made our website secure, but many browsers block pages with a Tumblr feed embedded in it as it is only partially secure.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to put <script type="text/javascript" src="httpS://username.tumblr.com/js"></script> - But that does not work

Comment: Use the API: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2 The script method is old and maybe removed at any time.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that - I was trying to avoid this.  I need to insert the Blog into a Magento website - so limited access to coding.